# How to create a different report for each subset of a data frame with R markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a dataset that looks like

```
 City   Score   Count   Returns
 Dallas 2.9 61  21
 Phoenix    2.6 52  14
 Milwaukee  1.7 38  7
 Chicago    1.2 95  16
 Phoenix    5.9 96  16
 Dallas 1.9 45  12
 Dallas 2.7 75  45
 Chicago    2.2 75  10
 Milwaukee  2.6 12  2
 Milwaukee  4.5 32  0
 Dallas 1.9 65  12
 Chicago    4.9 95  13
 Chicago    5   45  5
 Phoenix    5.2 43  5
```

I would like to build a report using R markdown; however, for each city I need to build a report. The reason for this is that one city cannot see the report for another city. How do I build a report and save a PDF of it for each city?

Each report would need the median `Score`, mean `Count`, and mean `Returns`. I know that using `dplyr` I could simply use

```
finaldat <- dat %>%
            group_by(City) %>%
            summarise(Score = median(Score),
                      Count = mean(Count)  ,
                      Return= mean(Returns))
```

But the frustration comes from producing a report for each `City`. Also, this is a subset of the data, not the full data. That is, this report is extensive and is a report of the results, which is systematic, not different for each `City`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like a **[parameterized report](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html)** might be what you need. See the link for details, but the basic idea is that you set a parameter in the `yaml` of your `rmarkdown` report and use that parameter within the report to customize it (for example, by filtering the data by `City` in your case). Then in a separate R script, you `render` the report multiple times, once for each value of `City`, which you pass as a parameter to the `render` function. Here's a basic example:

In your `Rmarkdown` report you would declare the parameter in the `yaml`. The listed value, `Dallas` in this case, is just the default value if no other value is input when you render the report:

```
---
title: My Document
output: pdf_document
params:
   My_City: Dallas
---
```

Then, in the same `Rmarkdown` document you would have your entire report--whatever calculations depend on `City`, plus the boilerplate that's the same for any `City`. You access the parameter with `params$My_City`. The code below will filter the data frame to the current value of the `My_City` parameter:

````
```{r}
dat %>%        
    filter(City==params$My_City) %>%
    summarise(Score = median(Score),
              Count = mean(Count)  ,
              Return= mean(Returns))
```
````

Then, in a separate R script, you would do something like the following to produce a separate report for each `City` (where I've assumed the Rmarkdown file above is called `MyReport.Rmd`):

```
for (i in unique(dat$City)) {
    rmarkdown::render("MyReport.Rmd", 
                      params = list(My_City = i),
                      output_file=paste0(i, ".pdf"))
}
```

In the code above, I've assumed the `dat` data frame is in the global environment of this separate R script that renders `MyReport.Rmd`. However, you could also just provide a vector of city names instead of getting the names from `unique(dat$City)`.

##### To use a dynamic title (see question in comments):

You can use parameters in the title (and other YAML metadata, such as author). For example:

**rmd file**

```
---
title: "Data for `r params$city`"
output: pdf_document
params:
  city: Dallas
---

Body of report
```

**Separate R script to render the rmd file**

Compile the rmd file for two cities:

```
for (i in c("New York", "Los Angeles")) {
  rmarkdown::render("test1.Rmd", 
                    params = list(city = i),
                    output_file=paste0(i, ".pdf"))
}
```

See the [R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/dynamic-yaml.html) for additional info.

Comment: So you have to separate a script from the R markdown to loop trhough? Would it be more effective to create a function to do this?

Comment: Yes to your first question (AFAIK). I don't know of a way to do it within the Rmarkdown document. As for your second question, if you're going to do this regularly, it might make sense to create a function to do it. Especially if you want to make it easy to customize or generalize the report.

Comment: I am still not clear as to why I need to specify `My_City: Dallas` in my `Rmarkdown`? Does it change when I use the `for` loop?

Comment: Yes, because `params = list(My_City = i)` passes each `City` into the `render` function, changing that parameter each time through the loop. I suppose you could leave `My_City:  ` blank in the Rmarkdown document and see if it throws an error.

Comment: See update to my answer. You can use parameters in the report title and/or other YAML metadata.

Comment: Its odd for the title i get this error message `! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ^^[ (U+001B)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX`.

Comment: Ok it worked. It didn't accept before because my title had a decimal and was numeric.