# Is it possible to automate R markdown files?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I need to generate a thousand R Markdown files, each essentially the same, just with different titles and a different subset of the data. Is there a way to store those titles and subsets in objects and automate creating and knitting the R Markdown files?

Comment: Yes.  You want to search for "Parameterized Reports." You may write a script to loop through your conditions and pass the parameters to the template with the correct data and titles.  For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32479130/passing-parameters-to-r-markdown

Comment: Here's another similar question with a great answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38572219/how-to-create-a-different-report-for-each-subset-of-a-data-frame-with-r-markdown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. When you klick the knit button in Rstudio, it calls the function
`rmarkdown::render()`. This can also be done in code, either in a `for` loop, with `apply` or the `purrr`-version of apply called `map`. You will need to create a rmarkdown-document that takes parameters for the title and the subset first and then pass these to the render-function in said way.

For an introduction to paramters in your documents have a look at the [documentation here](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!