# how to generate multiple reports including plots using variable data in R

Tags: r, variables, report, reporting

I have a table containing the following

```
myDF <- data.frame(Roll_No=c(1, 2), Student_Name= c(John, Bobby), Q1=c(77, 64), Q2=c(89, 83), Q3=c(55, 84), Q4=c(73, 81), Final=c(73.5, 78), Remarks=c("First Class", "Distinction"), Comment=c("Cleared with First Class", "Cleared with Distinction"))
```

```
Roll_No    Student_Name    Q1    Q2   Q3   Q4   Final     Remarks      Comment
1          John           77    89   55   73    73.5    First Class   Cleared with First Class
2          Bobby          64    83   84   81    78.00   Distinction   Cleared with Distinction
```

The above table is created by merging students and grades tables using merge and then classifying grades and using paste for creating comments

I need to create Progress report cards for each student with their data and a line-plot (marks on y-axis and Q1... Q4 on x-axis showing annual academic performance as per below sample

```
                   Roll No: 1      John

                   Cleared with Distinction

                         plot (line graph of johns academic performance)
```

I am not able to attach the plot /graph created in excel.

Is something like this possible in R ?

Comment: An almost identical question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38572219/3339295. `RMarkdown` is your friend.

Comment: @monarque I have tried the R markdown.. and it does give an output.. however i am stuck on formatting. the text at times goes beyond the page. also is there a way to add a background image or have the comment in a text box ?